# Managing Users With Multiple Roles & Properties

Tags: tables, roles

I need to manage a list of users who can have different roles on different websites. A user could manage up to 20 websites. I'm trying to find the best way to organize this information. The image below fails in that it does not show each user's role per each website. It would also get messy real quick if the user belongs to many websites.

[image]

Comment: Does the eventual UI also have to function as a CRUD interface? or are you just looking for a way to show a read-only list of all the websites a user is associated with?

Comment: It would also need to function as CRUD. I'm hoping to avoid uniquely listing each website & role combo. I'm also hoping to avoid adding any filters. The final solution does not need to be a table though.

Comment: In situations like this we use expanding table rows. Like this http://bit.ly/2knD8JC  - That at least would solve your location issue. Is something like that feasible?

Comment: Either expanding table rows like what @dennislees said or have a View action that either opens another page or shows a modal of more complete info.

Comment: @dennislees I think that is the best solution given my restrictions. Thank you for the suggestion. jen +1 for similar line of thought.

Comment: I added this as an answer, and also included an option for when you need to show a long list item, but the interactions are simpler.

Answer (score 4):

**For complex interactions (e.g. CRUD) on table rows, consider an expanding row**

This provides the space for your interactions.

[image]

**For simple interactions (e.g. read-only lists), consider a modal window.**

I think the way Facebook lets users review all the likes on a given item is a good example of this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also try displaying is statistical way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could present the overflowing row information as follows:

In case the websites managed by the user begin to overflow, you could include a chip that presents the count of overflowing websites, including the one that is partially overflowing.
[image: Chips to present overflowing website count]

As the user hovers over the particular chip, the user is shown a floating modal that presents the list of all the overflowing websites. This view facilitates quick view in case the user is merely browsing the table.
[image: floating modal to present the list of overflowing websites]

Also, if you notice, I have incorporated a drop-down chevron at the end of each row. In case you wish to present a detailed view of the user with all their information, say his/her contact, their company etc. you could create an expanded view in the form of an accordion that expands and collapses as the user acts on the row element.